# Why is chrome.tabs.query() only allowing me to update some tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been fiddling around with chrome extensions for a few days now to learn more about how they work. I am trying to make a simple extension that adds "/about" to the end of the url for every webpage. This bit of code works for several pages, such as chrome://extensions, chrome://settings, etc., but does not work for others, such as https://www.google.com, https://www.amazon.com, etc. Can anyone point to the problem with my code?

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true, status: "complete"}, function(array_of_Tabs) {
    var activeTab = array_of_Tabs[0];
    var url = activeTab.url;
    chrome.tabs.update({url: url + "/about"});
    window.close();
});

});
```

I apologize for any bad code, I am just getting started learning javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the background script or the contentscript?

Comment: This is in the background script

Comment: What are the permissions of your manifest file?